# Laravel NULL dates are valid "today" dates

Tags: mysql, laravel, date

In my Laravel 5.8 app, I have a model containing to dates: resubmission and deadline. Both are nullable (in the migration and thus in the current SQL database) and are set to `$dates = ['resubmission', 'deadline']` in the model itself. I have a set of 500 models in the database that have resubmission set to a date in the future. However, for testing purposes, I ran the query (`update <tablename> set resubmission=null, deadline=null`) so that all the models now have NULL values in their `resubmission` and `deadline` fields.

Sounds fair so fair, however, `$model->resubmission` is today - I'm returned a valid date string referencing the date of today. The exact same goes for `deadline` and I have no idea why this is happening since Laravel (to my knowledge) doesn't cache the database itself and thus I truly wonder where these dates are coming from. What I'll need, sure enough, is NULL values returned.

I googled but couldn't find anything related to exactly what happens in this scenario. Looking for some support.

Comment: You should be getting `null` values if the records are `null` in the database and if you don't override the accessors of those columns. For example for the resubmission, do you maybe have `getResubmissionAttribute` in your model, where you return todays date as a default?

Comment: I absolutely have. I think I see where this is coming from. I'd say thanks in advance (am pretty sure)

Comment: I guess `Carbon::parse($input)` just returns `now()` if `$input` is NULL. And that's where it's coming from...

Comment: Yes it does. So you should be checking the `$input` before you parse it.

Comment: `Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model` class uses `Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes` trait which has a method `getDates()` which gets the attributes that should be converted to dates and convert them using `asDate()` or `asDateTime()` methods. https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be getting `null` values if the records are `null` in the database and if you don't override the accessors of those columns.

For example having `getRessubmissionAttribute()` in the model and parsing the date with a `null` value using `Carbon` will return today's date.

Comment: You didn't know my code but yet you did ;-) Thanks for the quick tip.